# Pendulum in a Turning Airplane

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, centrifugal-force, centripetal-force

My friend and I are having an argument over what happens with a pendulum hanging inside an airplane during a turn. Assuming that the airplane is making a standard 1 G coordinated turn, how does the pendulum react?

I believe because the pendulum is attached to the string, it is pulled by the plane and will be in exact alignment with the bank angle of the plane. My friend says that the pendulum has a weight and will be between the bank angle of the plane and parallel with the earths gravity.

My line of thinking is that since the plane produces lift which must be greater than the weight, that the net force acting on the pendulum is in line with the bank angle of the plane.  Since the pendulum is attached to the plane I don't see how its weight can be factored differently even if it is being pulled by the string which is lifted by the plane.

Can someone explain how the pendulum would react and the forces at work.

Comment: For clarification, I think the pendulum will remain perpendicular to the floor of the aircraft during the turn, just as it would in level unaccellerated flight.

Comment: It depends on whether, in a turn, the airplane wings are always at 90° to the total acceleration vector. If you were on a spinning fairground ride this would certainly be the case, but I'm not sure I'd swear it's always the case for airplanes.

Comment: One must be careful: during level flight, an airplane (or at least the wing surface) must have a nonzero attitude, or pitch. The pendulum, though, will point straight down, and thus be at an angle wrt the airplane to begin with.  Anyway, start simple: if an automobile cuts a sharp turn, where does the pendulum (suspended from the roof) point?

Comment: What is a "standard 1D coordinated turn"?  Pilots may know, but the set of physicists who are not pilots do not.  :)

Comment: I agree with @garyp , a diagram would be very useful too!

Answer (score 4):

**In short, you are right, the pendulum has an angle with respect to the gravity vector, but your reference frame has this same angle, making them aligned.**

A 1-G coordinated turn is a turn such that the horizontal component of the lift is equal and opposite to the force generated by centrifugal acceleration. E.g like this:

[image]

Obtained from [Free online pilot ground school](http://www.free-online-private-pilot-ground-school.com/Aerodynamics_in_flight.html)

The pendulum will experience the same acceleration as the aircraft, thus gravity and centrifugal acceleration.

It all depends on the reference frame, since this defines what you see as down, and sideways.

An external observer, which defines down in the direction of the gravity vector, will say that there is an angle between the pendulum and the 'down'-direction.

If you are on the plane, and you define down as the place place where your feet are (thus in the opposite direction of the lift), you will see that the pendulum aligns with your feet, and thus there will be no angle between 'down' and the pendulum.